# Как сделать чтобы vk_api могло запоминать с кем общаться

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Как сделать чтобы бот в вк мог брать ник пользователя из профиля, и как пример мог писать когда у пользователя день рождения. Писал ему поздравления

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения информации о нике и дате рождения можно воспользоваться методом [`users.get`](https://vk.com/dev/users.get).

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi


vk_session = VkApi(token='[token]')
vk = vk_session.get_api()

r = vk.users.get(user_ids=1, fields='screen_name, bdate')[0]
print(f"Ник: {r['screen_name']}\nДата рождения: {r['bdate']}")
```

***stdout:***

```py
Ник: durov
Дата рождения: 10.10.1984
```

***Пример бота (`Long Poll` v5.103):***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


ACCESS_TOKEN = ''  # Подставьте свой!
GROUP_ID =         # Подставьте свой!


def main():
    vk_session = VkApi(token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
    vk = vk_session.get_api()

    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, GROUP_ID)
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            message = event.obj['message']
            user_id = message['from_id']

            user_info = vk.users.get(user_ids=user_id, fields='screen_name, bdate')[0]
            screen_name = user_info.get('screen_name')
            bdate = user_info.get('bdate')

            vk.messages.send(
                peer_id=message['peer_id'],
                message=f'Ник: {screen_name}\nДата рождения: {bdate}',
                random_id=get_random_id(),
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Я что-то не понял, почему  он выводит "Ник: durov
Дата рождения: 10.10.1984". Что надо заменить

Comment: @Mamora Параметр `user_ids` — уникальный идентификатор пользователя(ей).

Comment: а как его должен его узнать бот без моего участия

Comment: @Mamora Способов очень много. Например, взять из объекта `message`, когда пользователь отправляет сообщение боту.

Comment: `for event in longpoll.listen():
if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
text = event.object.text.lower()
print(message)
r = vk.users.get(user_ids = 1, fields='screen_name, bdate')[0]
print(f"Ник: {r['screen_name']}\nДата рождения: {r['bdate']}")`

Comment: У меня выпадает ошибка

Comment: @Mamora Конечно, это вызовет ошибку. Во-первых, приведите этот код в вопрос. Во-вторых, укажите версию `Long Poll`, которую Вы используете (это важно, посмотреть можно на одноимённой вкладке в настройках сообщества).

Comment: from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

Comment: @Mamora Я привёл пример, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "bot.py", line 17, in main
    message = event.obj['message']
KeyError: 'message'`
Вылезает ошибка

Comment: @Mamora Я уже спрашивал, но сделаю это ещё раз: какую версию `Long Poll` Вы используете? Это важно! Бота проверял на последней — 5.103.

Comment: А как переустановить Long Poll на новую версию? Я скачивал 25.03.20

Comment: @Mamora В настройках сообщества, на вкладке `Long Poll`.

Comment: Переустановил,теперь другая ошибка Traceback (most recent call last):
`  File "bot.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "bot.py", line 22, in main
    bdate = user_info['bdate']
KeyError: 'bdate' `

Comment: @Mamora Значит пользователь скрыл информацию о своём дне рождения. Добавьте в код проверку на это или используйте метод `get`. Сейчас приведу пример.

Comment: Cпасибо огромное!